# PowerBI / Power Query Dynamic data in query

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Using PowerBI/PowerQuery I'm using the web connector to query a rest api which returns json. I'm converting that to a table and ending up with a single column of values (id's). Looks like this:

[image]

These ids now need to be used in subsequent web queries, one query for each id. This will then yield the 'real' data which I need to get to.

How can I iterate through those id's using each in a new web query?

I have a complete solution in Python and can just import the json files from the Python script into PBI, but I really want to be able to give the PBI report to a colleague who would not touch Python, so I'm keen to find a simple way to achieve this in PBI/PQ.

Would appreciate any pointers on how this could be achieved as simply as possible.

Comment: You can use `List.Generate` to produce a List of api calls.  There are examples both here on PQ and also on a few internet resources.

Comment: See for example https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/